# DAX FILTER works with DATE() literal, but not SELECTEDVALUE()?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

In PowerBI, I have a table of prices (ItemID, ItemName, Price, EffectiveStartDate, EffectiveEndDate), and I'm trying to return all the prices that are effective on a given date (selected by the user or the evaluation context. On my report canvas I have a table visual with all the items and the details (above). If I declare a variable and assign a literal value to it, the filters work fine.... like this:

```
VAR CurrentDate = 
    DATE(2022, 3, 15)
RETURN 
    FILTER ( 
        Ingredients, 
        [EffectiveStartDate] < CurrentDate 
            && [EffectiveEndDate] > CurrentDate 
    )
```

but if I try to assign CurrentDate the value from my harvester measure, it fails. (somehow the inequality filters are being ignored ).  I have a slicer (dropdown) to pick a date, and SELECTEDVALUE('DimDate'[Date}) to retrieve the value. But when I try to use that in my filter, it fails:

```
VAR CurrentDate = 
    SELECTEDVALUE('DimDate'[Date])
RETURN
    FILTER ( 
        Ingredients, 
        [EffectiveStartDate] < CurrentDate 
            && [EffectiveEndDate] > CurrentDate 
    )
```

Any idea why this is happening? And how do I fix it?

I was expecting the two filters to act the same (the literal filter with DATE() and with a variable, but not so. When I set the value of a variable using SELECTEDVALUE(), it seems to ignore the variable in my FILTER() statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a calculation to depend on a slicer, **You need a Measure, NOT a Calculated column or Calculated table**. Calculated columns and calculated tables are generated on refresh and physically stored in your model, so the slicers can filter them, but the slicers can't change the value of the calculations.

Measures are not persistent but are calculated as needed based on changes to filters and slicers. E.g. you could use a measure like the following one to filter ingredients:

```
Filtered Ingredients = 
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE(DimDate[Date])
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Ingredients[Name]),
        Ingredients[EffectiveStartDate] < CurrentDate
            && Ingredients[EffectiveEndDate] > CurrentDate
    )
```